# What does the default /etc/profile on Mac OS X 10.8 look like?

Tags: macos, unix, shell, default-settings

Someone chump edited my `/etc/profile` file, and I want to revert it to the system default, because I have now realized that I would rather override whatever needs to be overridden using files in my home directory. Is there a way to reset the file contents to exactly how these were right after installation? Alternatively, quote the original contents so I can paste these into the file?

P.S. The chump is of course yours truly, from time past.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Contents on OS X 10.8.3 from [Apple's Open Source web site](http://www.opensource.apple.com/source/bash/bash-86.1/profile):

```
# System-wide .profile for sh(1)

if [ -x /usr/libexec/path_helper ]; then
        eval `/usr/libexec/path_helper -s`
fi

if [ "${BASH-no}" != "no" ]; then
        [ -r /etc/bashrc ] && . /etc/bashrc
fi
```

---

For a more general solution (or when you don't find it on opensource.apple.com), you can use [Pacifist](http://www.charlessoft.com/): It allows you to open the OS installer package on the OS X 10.8 DVD or disk image (`InstallESD.dmg`, part of the App Store download) and reinstall single files from these packages.

[image: Pacifist Screenshot]